# Can I use full-text mysql query in subquery in clause from

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, subquery, left-join

I want create search system in my website but I have some problem .

I have two table the name is shops and product.
I have some shop in table and maybe some shop have some pruduct maybe not.
If each customer search something if the word match with shop name query first list shop info then if we have some shops products match with this word then add to list. It has a relevance query .

> my table engine is innodb and version is 5.6+ error message is :
>
> ## 1214 - The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes

I use this query but I know it's not true and have error message, but I don't know how I can fix it to perform my idea.

```
select `shops`.`name`,`shops`.`nName`,`product`.`productname`,`product`.`productnName`,
 ((MATCH (`shops`.`name`,`shops`.`nName`) AGAINST ('apple' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 2) + 
 (MATCH (`product`.`productname`,`product`.`productnName`) AGAINST ('apple' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 1.5)) as `relevance`
 from `shops` left OUTER JOIN 
 (select `productname`,`productnName`,`sId` from `product` where  MATCH (`productname`,`productnName`) AGAINST ('apple' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) as `product` on (`product`.`sId`=`shops`.`id`) 
 where 
 (
    MATCH (`shops`.`name`, `shops`.`nName`) AGAINST ('apple' IN BOOLEAN MODE) and
    MATCH (`product`.`productname`, `product`.`productnName`) AGAINST ('apple' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
 ) 
 or 
    MATCH (`shops`.`name`, `shops`.`nName`) AGAINST ('apple' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
 or
    MATCH (`product`.`productname`, `product`.`productnName`) AGAINST ('apple' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
 ORDER BY `relevance` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add `FULLTEXT` indexes to your tables.

```
ALTER TABLE shops
ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (`name`,`nName`);

ALTER TABLE product
ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (`productname`,`productnName`);
```

Edit : I think you are losing the fulltext index in the subselect, give this a go.

```
select `shops`.`name`,`shops`.`nName`,`product`.`productname`,`product`.`productnName`,
 ((MATCH (`shops`.`name`,`shops`.`nName`) AGAINST ('apple' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 2) + 
 (MATCH (`product`.`productname`,`product`.`productnName`) AGAINST ('apple' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 1.5)) as `relevance`
 from `shops`,`product`
 where 
    MATCH (`shops`.`name`, `shops`.`nName`) AGAINST ('apple' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
 or
    MATCH (`product`.`productname`, `product`.`productnName`) AGAINST ('apple' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
 ORDER BY `relevance` DESC
```

Comment: I add fulltext index before for these tables but i think when subquery make new table it doesn't support fulltext.

Comment: I wrote this code but it have a issue . because if customer search shop name then get shop and n number of shop product . For this issue i use subquery and left join for product in from clause